# Lightning datatable header bottom border missing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-datatable

When I scroll the table to the right, the bottom border of the header row is not showing. In the next image we can see that the border disappear just before the third column cell ends.

[image]

This is the part of the component where the datatable is.

```
<div class="slds-box">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <b>Foo</b>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning:button class="slds-float_right" variant="brand-outline" label="Foo Button" onclick="{!c.fooAction}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-top_large">
        <lightning:datatable class="slds-scrollable_x"
            keyField = "fooKey"
            data="{!v.fooDataList}" 
            columns="{!v.fooColumns}"
            minColumnWidth="150"
            columnWidthsMode="auto"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The header row is built in this part of the Javascript helper.

```
Object.entries(response.headerFields).forEach(([apiName, value]) => {
    if(value[0] === "PICKLIST" || value[0] === "STRING") {
        value[0] = 'text';
    } else if (value[0] === "BOOLEAN") {
        value[0] = 'boolean';
    }
    var fooMap = { label : value[1], fieldName : apiName, type : value[0] };
    target.push(fooMap);
});
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue or why it's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Your hunch about the columns in the table is likely correct. What if you prevent the datatable from rendering until `v.fooColumns` is set?

Comment: I surrounded the div with `<aura:if isTrue="{!isLoading}"><aura:set attribute="else">`. The `isLoading` attribute is set to true as default value and is set to false when the data initialization finish but it doesnt seem to work neither. Is there any other way to render the table after the columns are set? Thank you.

Comment: The SLDS styles assume the table will never exceed 100% width, which I think is the problem.